# declaring a variable as a string that starts with a specific character, and then taking it through a for-loop

Tags: excel, vba

For part of my code, I need to take a string value in a  cell (ex. G1,G2,H3), select each term separated by a comma that starts with G, and then take each term through a for-loop. This way, only the terms starting with G go through the for-loop

This is what I have so far, and it seems to work except for my "part" variable. It remains empty. Is there an issue with my syntax or with my logic?

Thanks in advance.

```
dim parts, p as string 

part = "G" & "*" 'I tried both string and variant for part. I've also tried writing part="G*" instead

parts = o.Cells(cell.Row, "C") 
        
p = Split(parts, ",") 
        
        
For Each part In p
.
.
.
Next part
```

New updated working code:

```
dim parts, part as String
dim p As Variant 

parts = o.Cells(cell.Row, "C") 

p = Split(parts, ",") 

For k = LBound(p) to UBound(p)

If Left(Trim(p(k)), 1) = "G" Then

part = CSTR(p(k))

.
.
.
.

End If
Next k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays should be iterated over using a regular `For...Next` loop, and `Lbound` and `Ubound`. Then, check if the first character of each element is `G`. It's probably worth calling `Trim` as well to remove a potential leading space:

```vb
Dim i as Long
For i = Lbound(p) to Ubound(p)
   If Left(Trim(p(i)), 1) = "G" Then
      ...
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry but could you please elaborate? I've never worked with arrays in vba, but would I basically just define p as an array and then pickup from the part of the code you wrote?

Comment: [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) returns an array, so it should be `Dim p() as Variant`.